# Avoid the usage of a switch statement when parsing

Tags: swift, parsing, switch-statement, instantiation

I have been struggling to develop a code to avoid a big switch statement.

Basically I am given a set of tuples as input and now I would like to instantiate the appropriate class depending on the type specified in the tuple (first element of the tuple - e.g. ("Apple", ...)).

Currently I solved my problem by using a switch statement but this is a very bad idea if the number of classes increase in the future. Is there some elegant way to circumvent this issue?

Thank you!

```
class Apple {
    var color = ""
}

class Banana {
    var isTasty = false
}

let input = [("Apple", "green"),("Banana", "TRUE")]

for (type, value) in input {
    switch type {
    case "Apple":
        Apple()
    case "Banana":
        Banana()
    default:
        print(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly some factory patterns would be worth looking into. Although if your *switch statement* works for now, I would personally keep it for now and let the future dictate a different approach if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out,

```swift
// Parent Class to group them
class Fruit {
    var baseValue: Any
    required init(_ this: Any) {
        baseValue = this
        (self as? Apple)?.color = this as! String
        (self as? Banana)?.isTasty = this as! Bool
        // You can add more subclasses here
    }
}

class Apple: Fruit, Equatable {
    var color = ""
    
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(color)
    }
    static func == (lhs: Apple, rhs: Apple) -> Bool {
        return lhs.color == rhs.color
    }
}

class Banana: Fruit, Equatable {
    var isTasty = false
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(isTasty)
    }
    static func == (lhs: Banana, rhs: Banana) -> Bool {
        return lhs.isTasty == rhs.isTasty
    }
}
```

It's a little annoying that they have to conform to Fruit, Hashable, and Equatable. But it let's you do this, which answers your question:

```swift
let input: [(Fruit.Type,Any)] = [(Apple.self, "green"),(Banana.self, true)]

for (type, value) in input {
    // Now you don't need that switch statement
    let foo = type.init(value)
    // Now you can use `as?` to find out what it is
    
    print((foo as? Banana)?.isTasty)
    // See, it prints `nil` first, then `Optional(true)` next.
    // Which is how we want it to run
}
```

---

However, I think we can do even better.

```swift
enum Fruit {
    case apple(color: String)
    case banana(isTasty: Bool)
}

let input: [Fruit] = [.apple(color: "red"), .banana(isTasty: true)]
```

Much better.